# Pandas - Group / Aggregate rows based on duplication AND the existence of an opposite

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that sometimes contains 2 rows for what is, in reality, one entry. The way to identify these is:

1. Columns: Not, Strike, Cents, SD, ED are identical
2. Column ExecutionTimestamp is going to be within a short period of time (<2.5min)
3. For a (+) in Structure, there exists an offsetting (-)

|  | Not | Strike | Cents | SD | ED | Structure | StartDate | EndDate | Index | DisseminationID | ExecutionTimestamp | EventTimestamp | FloatingRateResetFrequencyPeriod1 | TruncatedNotional | TDateID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 500 | 2.925 | 182.5 | 2 | 3 | (+) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | 2025-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372521736 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 11 | 500 | 2.925 | 182.5 | 2 | 3 | (+) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | 2025-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372530892 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 12 | 250 | 3.255 | 153.5 | 1 | 2 | (+) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372539195 | 2022-06-28 14:36:15 | 2022-06-28 14:36:15 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 13 | 250 | 3.255 | 153.5 | 1 | 2 | (+) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372533865 | 2022-06-28 14:37:11 | 2022-06-28 14:37:11 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 14 | 380 | 2.473 | 43 | 1 | 2 | (-) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372657384 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 15 | 380 | 2.473 | 43 | 1 | 2 | (-) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372657386 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 16 | 130 | 3.223 | 76 | 1 | 2 | (+) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372656023 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 17 | 130 | 3.223 | 76 | 1 | 2 | (+) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372656033 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 18 | 130 | 3.223 | 76 | 1 | 2 | (-) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372654200 | 2022-06-28 16:41:16 | 2022-06-28 16:41:16 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 19 | 130 | 3.223 | 76 | 1 | 2 | (-) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372654203 | 2022-06-28 16:41:16 | 2022-06-28 16:41:16 | 3M | False | 1 |

I am looking to combine these pairs of 2 whereby it will result in:

1. Columns Not, Strike, SD, ED stay the same.
2. Column Cents is added together
3. Column Structure is replaced with (=)
4. I dont care which timestamp is returned, whatever easy.

|  | Not | Strike | Cents | SD | ED | Structure | StartDate | EndDate | Index | DisseminationID | ExecutionTimestamp | EventTimestamp | FloatingRateResetFrequencyPeriod1 | TruncatedNotional | TDateID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 500 | 2.925 | 182.5 | 2 | 3 | (+) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | 2025-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372521736 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 11 | 500 | 2.925 | 182.5 | 2 | 3 | (+) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | 2025-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372530892 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 2022-06-28 13:41:01 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 12 | 250 | 3.255 | 153.5 | 1 | 2 | (+) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372539195 | 2022-06-28 14:36:15 | 2022-06-28 14:36:15 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 13 | 250 | 3.255 | 153.5 | 1 | 2 | (+) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372533865 | 2022-06-28 14:37:11 | 2022-06-28 14:37:11 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 14 | 380 | 2.473 | 43 | 1 | 2 | (-) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372657384 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 15 | 380 | 2.473 | 43 | 1 | 2 | (-) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372657386 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 2022-06-28 16:40:37 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 16 | 130 | 3.223 | 152 | 1 | 2 | (=) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372656023 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 3M | False | 1 |
| 17 | 130 | 3.223 | 152 | 1 | 2 | (=) | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 | USD | 372656033 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 2022-06-28 16:41:00 | 3M | False | 1 |

Comment: so, should A/B/C/D/E be identical to make a match? This would mean C will necessarily be 2*C in case of a match?

Comment: Also, can you have a '(-)' without a matching '(+)'?

Comment: Yep. C represents a size in reality.  So when these 2rows issues show up, its only representing half the actual size.  if that makes sense...

Comment: No, you would need a matching (+).   There are many cases of standalone (-) and (+) that don't have a pair that should be left alone.

Comment: So, you mean 'Yes', there can be lone '(-)' (which you don't have in your example) ;)

Comment: haha, sorry.   Yes, there can be lone (-) that I didnt include in my sample data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246200/discussion-between-keynesiancross-and-mozway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a custom group and a `merge_asof` on (+) with back insertion of the lone (-) values:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

df['ExecutionTimestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ExecutionTimestamp'])

# identify + rows
m = df['F'].eq('(+)')

# merge
out = (pd
  .merge_asof(df[m].reset_index(), df[~m].reset_index(),
              by=cols, on='ExecutionTimestamp',
              direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2.5min'),
              suffixes=(None, '_')
             )
  .assign(F=lambda d: np.where(d['F_'].isna(), d['F'], '(=)'),
          C=lambda d: np.where(d['F_'].isna(), d['C'], d['C']*2), 
         )
 )

# add missing (lone) (-) value
missing = df.index.difference(out[['index', 'index_']].stack())

out = (pd
       .concat([out.set_index('index'), df.loc[missing]])
       .drop(columns=['index_', 'F_'])
      )
```

output:

```
      A      B    C         D        E    F  ExecutionTimestamp
15  130  3.123   77  0.975342  1.97808  (+) 2022-06-28 13:41:00
16  130  3.123  154  0.975342  1.97808  (=) 2022-06-28 16:41:00
17  130  3.223  152  0.975342  1.97808  (=) 2022-06-28 16:41:00
```

Comment: Thanks!  Only thing is that it doesn't aggregate "C".     Would you mind explaining to me this portion? "if len(g)==1"

Comment: @keynesiancross let me read again, I think I misunderstood the question

Comment: Making some edits to try and make it easier to understand, hopefully helps.

Comment: OK, got it I think, check the update ;)

Comment: Would you mind explaining this part tome...: # add missing (lone) (-) value

Comment: A `merge_asof` is only a left merge. Which means that the lone + are kept but not the lone -. So we need to add them back. In your particular case this is not obvious as there is no lone -, but try to add one to see the difference.

Comment: its not exactly working my side, but its probably because I oversimplified this example... thanks for your help!  I'll try to bash it out from here.

Comment: Do you have a second or two for a couple quick questions on that chat?  To avoid cluttering this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246205/discussion-between-mozway-and-keynesiancross).

Comment: It's probably easier if you ask your questions here, I'm also busy IRL so I can't commit to be 100% available on chat ;)

Comment: Made edits! Thanks.    When I ran your code, and changed column names to IRL ones, I ended up with a kind of mangled df.  lot of NaNs (maybe concat not working correctly?).  And I think the add-back didn't work correctly, as its adding back some of the pair'ed (-)

Comment: I dont think the add-back works, as it pulls back in some of the missing pairs

Comment: It shouldn't, it's based on the index. Do you have duplicated indices?

Comment: Whats the best way to show you?

Comment: Can you provide the example as DataFrame constructor? Easier to use on a phone

Comment: Oh - I see why its happening.  When you do the merge, it assumes that there are no duplicates in (-).  In this case, it was merging the same (-) twice, leaving one remaining which got added back later.

Comment: So did you solve it? But sure what to do with the updated example the columns are different

Comment: I didn't solve it exactly, but I'm kind of bashing my way through it using intermediate steps of what your code did.  Sorry it was such a messy question!

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry when I typed the answer, I'll try to comment when I have a moment

Comment: All good - I got it thanks!   Next time I should just commission you for an hour, it would seem far more productive!

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to get your expected results.

```
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'D', 'E']).agg({'C' : 'sum', 'ExecutionTimestamp' : 'last'}).reset_index()
df['F'] = '(=)'
df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'ExecutionTimestamp']]
```

I was sure what you meant by the "keep either timestamp" if you meant that you could manually choose which one of the timestamps you wanted or if you were willing to accept either. I just assumed you would want the 'last' one in my code, but you can change that to 'first' if you would prefer the first encounter value.

Comment: Thanks for the post! that does work but I think only in a select case (my fault with the data I gave).  I edited the question with an additional row of data to make it more representative.

Comment: Your question is still a little difficult to understand, is the fact that one has a + and needs to be grouped only because there is a corresponding - a factor?

Comment: Yes exactly.  One positive, one negative.